# in Xcode how do I optionally append an end date to a string if it does not equals the start date

Tags: xcode, ios6, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am new to xcode and object oriented development (was databasic back in the day...) and am trying to build a string based on whether or not the start date is the same as the end date, so if it is the same just return the start date and if not return the start and end date (i.e. 15/02/2013 - 17/02/2013). My code is as follows but it does not like the 'fulldatestring', is there something wrong with my if statement?

```
NSString *startDate = [info objectForKey:@"StartDate"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
NSDate *sdate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startDate];
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];
NSString *convertedStartDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:sdate];

NSString *endDate = [info objectForKey:@"EndDate"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
NSDate *edate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:endDate];
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];
NSString *convertedEndDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:edate];

if(convertedStartDate isEqualToString:convertedEndDate) {
    NSString *fulldatestring = convertedStartDate;
}
else
    NSString *fulldatestring = [convertedStartDate, convertedEndDate ];
{

cell.datesLabel.text = fulldatestring
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare NSDates, see the NSDate instance methods [isEqualToDate:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/isEqualToDate%3a) and [compare:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare%3a). You don't need to (and shouldn't) convert them to NSStrings to compare them.

Search the [NSString class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) for "append" and you'll see two methods that append one NSString to another.

That should put you in the right direction, but I can post code if you really need it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple issues with your Objective-C syntax.

Whenever sending a message to an object such a isEqualToString: to a string it must be in square brackets. as well your braces around the if statement don't match.

```
if([convertedStartDate isEqualToString:convertedEndDate]) {
    NSString *fulldatestring = convertedStartDate;
} else {
    NSString *fulldatestring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", convertedStartDate, convertedEndDate];
}
```

As well NSString objects are not mutable so you cannot just concat them like you are trying to do you must create a new NSString object.

Comment: John Sauer does have the better solution for comparing NSDate objects.

Comment: Thanks syntax was very useful.